# Applescript from Mac App says "Expected end of line but found \U201c\"\U201d."

Tags: objective-c, applescript, copy-paste, sandbox

I am trying to perform a copy/paste for my to the the last active app, here's my code:

```
NSString *appleScriptSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\ntell application \"%@\" to activate\ntell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"%@\"\nkeystroke \"v\" using command down\nend tell", [lastApp localizedName], [lastApp localizedName]];

NSDictionary *error;
NSAppleScript *aScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:appleScriptSource];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *aDescriptor = [aScript executeAndReturnError:&error];
```

The problem is that on some computers it works just fine, but on others it fails. My error output from error that is returned by executeAndReturnError is:

```
2012-06-13 17:43:19.875 Mini Translator[1206:303] (null) (error: {
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Expected end of line but found \U201c\"\U201d.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Expected end of line but found \U201c\"\U201d.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2741";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {95, 1}";
})
```

I can't seem to figure out what it means or why it happens.

We tried copying the generated apple-script code into the Apple Script editor, and here it works just fine.

My App is sandboxed - i have added the bundle identifiers for the key "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events" for the apps i want to support.

Any suggestions?

Comment: \U201c and \u201d both represent quotes (left/right respectively). [Typing quotes on a keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22#Typing_quotation_marks_on_a_computer_keyboard) So it makes me believe that you aren't escaping the quote " correctly. Play around with the format of the string and the characters you're escaping in it.

Comment: Well i have translated the unicodes but i can't really figure out what goes wrong. I have tried playing with the apple script but it does not work - the weird part is that it works on some macs.

Comment: Even doing simple applescripts like "active this app" produces the same error.

Comment: [link](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/196704-shell-script-in-applescript.html) Looks like you need escape quotes multiple times.

Comment: Check the link, it seems repetitive but apparently \\\" varies from \" when using apple script.

Comment: The multi escape are for the AppleScript command "**do shell script**" only.

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing that the \u201c and \u201d are red herrings and just represent smart quotes around a double quote in the error message produced by apple script, and your issue lies with the localized name of the last application you are formatting into the script. I am not sure why you might see this on one machine and not another.

For example if the name was 'Some " App' then the double quotes would end up mismatched as it would end up injected into the middle of a double quoted string. You might want to try and replace any double quotes in the name with '\"' which will escape them.

e.g.

```
NSString *esc = [[lastApp localizedName] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

Comment: this answer is applicable too when addressing quote issues in json. the unicodes were indeed red herrings.

Comment: The 'red herring' in my case was a missing \n before 'end tell'